# Asynchronously loading subcategories based on main category in a new list item

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-list

Is it possible to load a select box asynchronously (or populate it) based on a previous selection?

[image]

so for example, if I choose topic Miscellaneous, then it would load all the subtopics which are linked to Miscellaneous. Those 2 select boxes are made as Lookup from 2 different lists. TOPIC list is just titles of topics, SUB TOPIC list has the sub topic linked to the main topic (as a Lookup as well).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you mean cascade filtering for lookup columns. You can use [this manual](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/39842.cascading-of-lookup-dropdown-fields-on-sharepoint-2013-and-office-365.aspx).

*Hope it helps!*

Comment: Thanks for the manual, this was exactly what I needed! :)

Comment: you're welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

From your description, you want to create cascading Dropdowns. Most of us are familiar with such scenarios like Country, City are filled up one by one depending on selection of previous dropdownlist.

You can create 2 level Cascading Dropdown list in SharePoint List using Javascript.

You need to add a Content Editor Web Part into the page where you want to make cascading dropdown work. Then put the script in below article into the content editor Web Part:

http://microsoftsharepointdevelopment2010.blogspot.sg/2013/01/working-with-cascading-dropdown-in.html

Comment: Thank you as well! The above comment helped, therefore I didn't go over everything in your manual. But the comment you wrote seems to be exactly what I ended up doing! :)